# How to change location of 3x3 cube inside 6x6 cube

Tags: c#, recursion, figure, bmp

The problem : I can't change the location of 3x3 cube created inside 6x6 cube.

I will put pictures so it's much easier to understand the problem that I'm facing.

Code :

Xstart - starting location on X axis 
Ystart - starting location on Y axis
Xend - ending location on X axis
Yend - ending location on Y axis

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("sample.bmp", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    file.Write(header);
    int l = (1000 + 31) / 32 * 4;
    var t = new byte[1000 * l];
    RecursiveFigure(t, l, 2, 1000, 1000, 0, 0);
    file.Write(t);
}
static void RecursiveFigure(byte[] t,int l, int recursiveCount, double Xend, double Yend, double Xstart, double Ystart)
{
    if (recursiveCount == 1)
    {
        CreateNet(t, l, 3, Xend, Yend, Xstart, Ystart);
        //CreateBlackBox(t, Xend, Yend, l, 3, Xstart, Ystart);
        return;
    }
    CreateNet(t, l, 6, Xend, Yend, Xstart, Ystart);
    //CreateBlackBox(t, Xend, Yend, l, 6, Xstart, Ystart);
    RecursiveFigure(t, l, recursiveCount - 1, Xend / 6, Yend / 6, 0, 0);
}
static void CreateNet(byte[] t, int l, int boxSize, double Xend, double Yend, double Xstart, double Ystart)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < boxSize; i++)
    {
        int k = Convert.ToInt16(i * Yend / boxSize); // boxSize is always 6x6, except when doing last recursion its 3x3
        int x = Convert.ToInt16(i * Xend / boxSize); // boxSize is always 6x6, except when doing last recursion its 3x3
        DrawVerticle(t, x, l, Ystart, Yend);
        DrawHorizontal(t, k, l, Xstart, Xend);
    }
}
static void DrawVerticle(byte[] t, int s, int l, double Ystart, double Yend)
{
    for (int y = (int)Ystart; y < Yend; y++)
    {
        int index = (y * l) + (s / 8);
        if (index < t.Length)
            t[index] |= (byte)(0x80 >> (s % 8));
    }
}
static void DrawHorizontal(byte[] t, int k, int l, double Xstart, double Xend)
{
    for (int x = (int)Xstart; x < Xend; x++)
    {
        int index = (k * l) + (x / 8);
        if (index < t.Length)
            t[index] |= (byte)(0x80 >> (x % 8));
    }
}
```

[What I currently have]  (https://prnt.sc/GKbRNwUL991U)]
[Goal]  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/s348h.png)

I was wondering if someone might see the problem in the code or solution. Also, maybe someone has seen any kind of youtube video that explains more about structures on BMP file using recursive.

First idea that came to my mind was to connect vertical and horizontal lines methods into 1 method and use double for cycles but that didn't work for me (might have it done wrong).

```
for (int y = (Height / 6 / 3); y < (Height / 6 / 3) * 2; y++)
{
    for (int x = (Width / 3 + Width / 6) + (Width / 6 / 3); x < ((Width / 3) * 2) - (Width / 6) / 3; x++)
    {
        int index = y * l + x / 8;
        t[index] |= (byte)(0x80 >> (x % 8));
    }
}
```

This is the method that I'm using to paint the middle cubes black and tried to recreate it to work with lines but it didn't work.

Comment: Your 'Goal' and 'current' images look the same to me. I would suggest using `Graphics.FromImage` and `DrawLine` methods instead of manually changing pixels. I would also recommend introducing better types, like point, line, box, etc, and use better variable names. None of your methods can be understood by just looking at the parameter list.

Comment: Realised that I made some mistakes. So I will try to fix them now, and change variables names so it would be easier to understand. Also, I changed pictures.

Comment: +1 to what JonasH wrote - not only does C# have Point, Brush, Line types etc, it also has transformations like rotation, translation. It also has [SIMD-accelerated types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/simd) like Vector and Matrix4x4 with [predefined transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.matrix4x4?view=net-8.0).

Comment: I'm aware that there are many other solutions, but my main goal is to do it while manually changing pixels. That is why I'm asking if maybe someone has watched a youtube video where it explains more about manually changing pixels or has an idea on how to fix the current problem. Also, I changed variables names so it would be easier to understand.

Comment: names like these are not very "useful" for clarity `t, int k, int l,`

Comment: L represents the number of bytes needed to store each row of a 2D array.
T - represent pixel data for an image.
k -is used to calculate the vertical position of the line.
x - is used to calculate the horizontal position of the line.

Comment: You seem to get actual images, so presumably the setting of pixels part works. But I don't see how this could ever produce your "goal" image, since that would require you to specify the coordinates where you want more detailed grids, and I can see nothing like that. Your `RecursiveFigure` will essentially just translate to two calls to `CreateNet`. I would personally make a method like `Rectangle[,] CreateGrid(Rectangle bounds, int xLines, yLines)`, since that would seem to fit the problem. Also, use a Debugger to help understand what your program is actually doing.

Comment: A cube is a 3-dimensional shape. But you only have two coordinates. In that case it is a square, not a cube.